# AccessControlException when connecting to HTTP server from Tomcat servlet

Tags: tomcat, permissions, securitymanager

I'm trying to make my tomcat servlet download a number of files, but I have apache and tomcat running on the same server, so I assume that is why it doesn't work. I've tested on servers not running apache, and all is well.

Here's the exception I'm getting when I try to use new Url( fileUrl ).openStream():

```
 Opening input stream Attempted to download: http://www.stefankendall.com/files/test.txt java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.stefankendall.com:80 connect,resolve)
```

How can I run http downloads via tomcat while running apache at the same time? Am I stuck?

**EDIT:**
No matter what I do, I can't get past tomcat. Here's 03catalina.policy:

// ========== CATALINA CODE PERMISSIONS =======================================

```
// These permissions apply to the logging API
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" {
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.util.logging.config.class", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.util.logging.config.file", "read";
        permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "shutdownHooks";
        permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}${file.separator}conf${file.separator}logging.properties", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "catalina.base", "read";
        permission java.util.logging.LoggingPermission "control";
        permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}${file.separator}logs", "read, write";
        permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}${file.separator}logs${file.separator}*", "read, write";
        permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
        // To enable per context logging configuration, permit read access to the appropriate file.
        // Be sure that the logging configuration is secure before enabling such access
        // eg for the examples web application:
        // permission java.io.FilePermission "${catalina.base}${file.separator}webapps${file.separator}examples${file.separator}WEB-INF${file.separator}classes${file.separator}logging.properties", "read";
};

// These permissions apply to the server startup code
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/bin/bootstrap.jar" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
 permission java.net.socketPermission "*:80", "connect, resolve";
};

// These permissions apply to the servlet API classes
// and those that are shared across all class loaders
// located in the "lib" directory
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/lib/-" {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
       permission java.net.socketPermission "*:80", "connect, resolve";
};

grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/-" {
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
 permission java.net.socketPermission "*:80", "connect, resolve";
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the presence or absence of some program running on the same box; it has to do with the presence of a SecurityManager in Tomcat (which, probably, means that you're running an old version of Tomcat).

Here is detailed documentation on [how to configure the Tomcat SecurityManager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/security-manager-howto.html). In your case, you'll add some lines to the local.policy file, along the lines of

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/-" {
  permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:80", "connect";
};
```

Comment: Clearly I did not understand the problem, as I believed my only setup difference to be the existence of apache. I'll try this and see if it works. The perils of using preconfigured software....

Comment: Changes need to be in 50local.policy.

Comment: Thanks for the "accept". Since I don't have edit privileges yet, may i suggest that you edit your question to say something like "AccessControlException when connecting to HTTP server from Tomcat servlet", or something like that?